# How to break out of a foreach once a condition is met?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a situation where when dealing with an object I generally use a foreach to loop through it like this:

```
foreach ($main_object as $key=>$small_object) {
...

}
```

However, I need to put a conditional in there like this:

```
foreach ($main_object as $key=>$small_object) {
   if ($small_object->NAME == "whatever") {
      // We found what we need, now see if he right time.
      if ($small_object->TIME == $sought_time) {
          // We have what we need, but how can we exit this foreach loop?
      }
}
```

What is the elegant way to do this? It seems wasteful to have it keep looping through if it's found a match. Or is there another approach to do this that is better? Possibly using for instead of foreach?

Comment: You mean `break;` ? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Can break be used in a foreach though? I see it in switch/case and with while, but does break work in a foreach? If so,is this a good programming style to use break this way?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From PHP documentation:

`break` ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

So yes, you can use it to get out of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `break`  statement inside the if condition:

```
if ($small_object->TIME == $sought_time) {
   break;       
}
```

`break` statement will break out of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
   $count = 0;
    ......
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ......    
    if (++$count == 5) break;
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.