# php array find value and store in db and stop loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an Array $column with two values: value and sum.
The array is ordered based on sum.
I want to store the first sum that is above 10 and stop the array so it is not storing the other values which are later in the array.
I tried different things including break; but this influences the rest of the script below it or is not working.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
<?php
foreach ($column as $value => $item) {
    if ($item['sum'] >= 10) {
        echo "First value above 10";
        // store value in Database and stop string so next values won't go into DB
    } else { 
        echo "lower than 10 and do nothing";
    }

    echo $item['value'] . " - " . $item['sum'] . " <br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps you: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Are you looking for `break`? Hard to understand.

Comment: Use `break` ?? Tried that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of a foreach once a condition is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012290/how-to-break-out-of-a-foreach-once-a-condition-is-met)

Comment: break is definitly a fitting solution if you want to stop the loop. If you just want to stop one functionality within the loop, you could use helper variables. I've not quite understand what you want to do, but I guess it can be something like `$storeInDB = true` before the loop, extend the condition to `if ($storeInDB && ..)` and set the variable to false after the first insert

Comment: Your question will gain clarity if you post some sample input data and your expected outcome from the data.

Comment: I don't want to use break because it will stop the complete php file and all the other command below these lines.

Comment: That is not correct.  If you place the break inside the foreach loop, it will only kill the loop then execute the remaining code in the file.

Comment: Again, please improve your question.  All questions on StackOverflow deserve a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. If I understand you still need to keep looping even after the fact you have found your first value over ten. You just need to store a boolean flag in that case keeping track of the fact whether or not you already found one:

```
<?php
    $itemFound = false;
    foreach ($column as $value => $item) {
        if (!itemFound && $item['sum'] >= 10) {
            echo "First value above 10";
            // query on connnection here
            $itemFound = true;
        } 
        echo $item['value'] . " - " . $item['sum'] . " <br />";
     }
?>
```

If you need help with the database query, you are going to need to give more information about your local configuration.

Comment: I implemented this, but then every line of the array containing a sum higher than 10 is stored. Only the first value above 10 need to be stored.
In this way the second item need to be stored as:
$itemFound = second
This way in the corresponding IF there won't have to be an SQL insert

Comment: that shouldn't be the case. are you sure you declared the Boolean flag $itemfound before the for loop?